# Why would you give a style tag an id

Tags: html, css

Hi have noticed a few sites that give the style tag an id such as:

```
<style id=style-id></style>
```

Can anyone explain firstly why you would do this and also the benefits of doin so?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

So you can reference it (just like any other element), i.e.

```
var styles = document.getElementById('style-id');
// do anything you want, like
styles.parentNode.removeChild(styles); // remove these styles
styles.setAttribute('href', 'alternate-styles.css'); // change the style
```

Comment: so you can use it to create dynamic styles using javascript then?

Comment: Yes, you can add or delete stylesheets, move them up and down in the page's DOM, or possibly even read their contents? (never tried it)  You can additionally style individual elements by change their `.style` properties (i.e. `document.body.style.backgroundColor='red';`), but I highly recommend a library for anything major.

Comment: Really cool way to add new style lines actually. I'm thinking about making a javascript function to add new lines of styles something like `function addStyle(newStyleLine)`, then i will use innerHTML to add the new class. I hope it will work, but i dont have any idea if it will be efficient?

Comment: Does removing a `<style>` or removing it's contents also remove them from the browser rendering?

Comment: This is a pratical use-case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505225/inject-css-stylesheet-as-string-using-javascript

Comment: You can always insert CSS rules to a stylesheet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule

Comment: I don't believe `href` is an attribute that can be applied to a `<style>` element. You may be thinking of the `<link>` tag.