# Include CSS (Sass) from multiple modules

Tags: javascript, sass, npm, gulp, browserify

I'm putting together a repo that will be available on npm. The repo consists of multiple modules, similar to [react-leaflet](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet) and [react-d3](https://github.com/esbullington/react-d3). Application developers will include modules from within the npm package via `require`/`import`, e.g.:

```
import { ModuleOne, ModuleTwo } from 'myNpmPackage`;
```

I need to package CSS along with each of these modules, and that CSS will be compiled from Sass files within each module.

Given a folder structure for `myNpmPackage` like:

```
├── src
│   ├── ModuleOne
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── style.scss
│   ├── ModuleTwo
│   │   ├── index.js
│   │   ├── style.scss
├── package.json
```

What is a good publish flow to make those `.scss` files (compiled into `.css`) available to consumers of `myNpmPackage`, without requiring that consumers explicitly include / `@import` / `link rel="stylesheet"` the CSS?

I'm using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and [browserify](http://browserify.org/) and would prefer to stick with that pipeline.

---

**UPDATE:** I've found [`parcelify`](https://github.com/rotundasoftware/parcelify) does *some* of what I need. I add the following to `myNpmPackage/package.json`:

```
"style": "src/**/*.scss",
"transforms": [
  "sass-css-stream"
]
```

and add `parcelify` to `dependencies`, so that it's installed along with `myNpmPackage`.

Consumers of `myNpmPackage` must then add the following to their `gulpfile`:

```
parcelify(b, {
    bundles: {
        style: './build/modules.css'
    }
});
```

`parcelify` will use the `"style"` glob in `myNpmPackage/package.json` to round up all the `.scss` files in `myNpmPackage`'s modules and bundle them into `./build/modules.css`.

This is getting there, but not ideal for two reasons:

1. The CSS files from each module are all included in the consumer application build, even if not all the modules are included;
2. This strategy requires the consumer application developer to add code to their `gulpfile` instead of "just working".

Comment: I know you want to stick with browserify but [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) is actually perfect for your use case

Comment: @JulienCabanès would you mind elaborating? Maybe you're more familiar with webpack than I and can share an example of how I'd do this with webpack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a Webpack setup](https://github.com/JulienCabanes/Webpack-Module-Example) that does exactly what you need:

- only imported modules CSS are included in [the build](https://github.com/JulienCabanes/Webpack-Module-Example/blob/master/dist/bundle.js) (`ModuleThree` is not for instance).
- no need to update some `gulpfile.js` or `*.config.js`, each module [`require` its own stylesheet(s)](https://github.com/JulienCabanes/Webpack-Module-Example/blob/master/src/ModuleOne/index.js#L1) like any other dependency.

**Bonus**: ModuleTwo shows [how to lazy load CSS](https://github.com/JulienCabanes/Webpack-Module-Example/blob/master/src/ModuleTwo/index.js#L2) and also contains a background image which will be included like any dependency as well.

**Note**: I didn't use ES2015 syntax but you could if you wish with [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader).

Comment: Thanks @Julien, this is great. I'm going to hold on accepting this answer since I'd rather not switch from browserify to webpack just yet...but I might change my mind soon :)

Comment: I realize I may be being a purist, but I'm not a fan of inlining the CSS into the HTML. Does webpack offer an option to compile required CSS/Sass files to a .css file instead of inlining?

Comment: Yes it does, with [this plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin). I've [updated](https://github.com/JulienCabanes/Webpack-Module-Example/commit/71e599e4d4bfe246035a8dbcfa2899e73137d063#diff-11e9f7f953edc64ba14b0cc350ae7b9d) my config and now I have a single [build stylesheet](https://github.com/JulienCabanes/Webpack-Module-Example/blob/master/dist/styles.css) (except lazy load) that I have to [include manually](https://github.com/JulienCabanes/Webpack-Module-Example/blob/master/index.html#L3) with a classic `link` tag.

Answer (score 1):

It depends partly on your own development pipeline. You could render out all your SCSS into CSS upon building your app. So assuming you have a single CSS file with all styles rendered out, you can include this into a JavaScript file using various methods within the gulp ecosystem for example [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-insert).

```
function addStyleString(str) {
    var node = document.createElement('style');
    node.innerHTML = str;
    document.body.appendChild(node);
}

addStyleString('/* CSS File 1 */');
```

And in your gulp pipeline:

```
var gfi = require("gulp-file-insert");

gulp.src('./sample.js')
  .pipe(gfi({
    "/* CSS File 1 */": "path/to/main.css"
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
```

Reference: [Inject CSS stylesheet as string using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505225/inject-css-stylesheet-as-string-using-javascript)

Comment: Not sure I feel great about the whole CSS-inlined-into-JS thing, a la Radium. But thanks for the suggestion.