# Webpack inject js/css file content directly to index.html

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I have code like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="path_to_css/some_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and I need plugin/loader or other way to get my html file with replaced link and script tags to content of this files, is there any way to do it?

Finnaly i wrote own plugin which fit my needs
[include-file-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/include-file-webpack-plugin)

Comment: I would try [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin).

Comment: this plugin can't do this or i can't do this using this plugin only what i want is put content of css file into html

Comment: @jagwedanfesa I guess you need to read the docs again.

Answer (score 5):

It actually can be accomplish with:

1. `npm i --save-dev css-loader to-string-loader`
2. configure your webpack with

   ```
   module: [
       rules: [
         {
           test: /\.css$/,
           use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
         }
       ]
     }
   ```
3. Then in your project you can access the css as string like so

   `const cssContent= require('path_to_css/some_css.css');
    console.log('your css is: ', cssContent.toString());`

   - Or maybe you want inject it manually to the page with:

     ```
     const boostrap= require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
     let style= document.createElement('style');
     style.id= 'boostrap';
     style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
     style.innerHTML= boostrap.toString();
     document.body.appendChild(style);
     ```

Reference

1. [Inject CSS stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505225/inject-css-stylesheet-as-string-using-javascript)
2. [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader)

Comment: how would you run that function from Webpack / runtime? I'm compiling ejs templates into a 1 one file webpage so cant run JS from the page.