# How to minimize webpack to-string-loader css?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, minify

I'm using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45452306/417620. It works great, but the CSS content that is returned has comments and is not minified.

```
module: [
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm using webpack 4. I've tried to use a number of different loaders, but they seem to no longer work with webpack 4 or they only work when the CSS is exported to a file. Is there anyway to remove the CSS comments and minify the CSS that is returned?

Here is the js that is returning the CSS as a string.
`import myCss from './myCss.css';`

Answer (score 3):

You need to give minimize option true to your css-loader

```
module: [
    rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: "to-string-loader",
            },
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: { minimize: true },
            },
          ],
       }
    ]
  }
```

`to-string-loader` will help to convert it to string. Minification will be taken care by `css-loader`.

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.

Comment: This does work if you use css-loader v1. In v2 css-loader has removed the option to minimize. Any idea how to make this work in the newest version or what the plan is moving forward?

Comment: Also this doesn't remove comments from the CSS. Any options on removing comments?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the issue using postcss-loader.

```
 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          "to-string-loader",
          "postcss-loader",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
```

*Reference*
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/postcss-loader/

Comment: This answer partially gets you there. You also need to make sure you install postcss and cssnano as dev dependencies and also to reference them in your package.json
```
"postcss": {
    "map": false,
    "plugins": {
      "cssnano": {}
    }
  },
```