# How to disable long press selection on WKWebView in iOS15?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios15

With the iOS 15 update, in my web application is appear a new functionality that I want to disable. This feature is based on a long press and dragging is possible to select some text.

**Feature example gif**

[image: Feature example gif]

i've tried to use:

```
WKWebViewConfiguration* conf = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKPreferences *preferences = [[WKPreferences alloc] init];
preferences.textInteractionEnabled = false;
conf.preferences = preferences;
```

but it disable all interactions with text, text inputs too.

Someone can help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just using CSS will solve your problem (write code below in your own html or css file):

```css
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

If you are not familiar with CSS，here is a sample code that inject CSS with JS in your Objective-C Code:

```objectivec
[webView evaluateJavaScript:@"function addStyle(){const style=document.createElement('style');style.textContent='user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none;';document.head.append(style)};addStyle();" completionHandler:NULL];
```

Ref：

[user-select - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)

[Inject CSS stylesheet as string using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15506705/4493393)