# Inject css inline into elements using js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

For example, my html code is as follows:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>add style inline in js</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="one">
     <div class="two">
        <a href="#">link</a>
     </div>
  </div>

  <script src="js/my-scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to select elements and style them in my-scripts.js file like css:

```
.one .two a:hover{color:red;}
```

I have a sample jquery code:

```
function injectStyles(rule) {
  var div = $("<div />", {
    html: '&shy;<style>' + rule + '</style>'
  }).appendTo("body");    
}

$("button").on("click", function() {
  injectStyles('a:hover { color: red; }');
});
```

> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/inject-new-css-rules/

but I want to do this without using jquery and without using the button.
(Apply styles after loading script file)

I want to define my css code in js and define each one separately as "inline" for each element.

Thanks to the professors

Comment: You can execute js code using the onload attribute on some elements. Cf []html tag onload(https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp)

Comment: For what reason are you attempting to do this? It's a terrible approach, and I'm sure there's a better method of doing whatever it is you require.

Comment: Sounds like a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505225/inject-css-stylesheet-as-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a template class in your css file like this

```css
.colorOnHover a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

And then you can use `document.querySelector` to get the element and add the `colorOnHover` to the classList of that element.

```js
// your js file
const element = document.querySelector(''); // pass in the ID or the class of the element you want to add the changes to
(function() {
    element.classList.add('colorOnHover');
})();
// this will add `colorOnHover` class to the classList and apply the css defined to the class in your css file.
```

Make sure to link the javascript & css file (if any) using `<script src = "pathHere" defer></script>` and `<link rel = 'stylesheet' href = "pathHere>"` respectively

**update** : since the op didn't want to use querySelector

You could use `document.createElement('style')` and append it to the html file, it would be similar to manually inserting a  tag

```js
(function() {
    const styleEl = document.createElement('style');
    styleEl.textContent = '.one .two a:hover{color:red;}';
    document.head.append(styleEl);
    console.log('added new style tag');
})();
```

Comment: i have 8000 line css code.  a faster method than queryselector. thanks

Comment: you mean 8000 line html file? because queryselector gets the element from your html it has nothing to do with css, if that's the case, assign a common base class name for all the elements you want to make the change to and use `querySelectorAll()`, use a loop to iterate through all elements and add the template class to its classlist

Answer (score 0):

This how to inject your CSS to to `<style>` tag :

JS & jQuery code :

```
function injectStyles(rule) {
  $("style").append(rule);
}

$("button").on("click", function() {
  injectStyles('.one .two a:hover{color:red;}');
});
```

HTML code :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>add style inline in js</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js" integrity="sha512-n/4gHW3atM3QqRcbCn6ewmpxcLAHGaDjpEBu4xZd47N0W2oQ+6q7oc3PXstrJYXcbNU1OHdQ1T7pAP+gi5Yu8g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="one">
     <div class="two">
        <a href="#">link</a><br>
       <button type="button">Make the link hover Red</button>
     </div>
  </div>

  <script src="js/my-scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```