# How to change in javascript background color from css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having problems changing the css in javascript.
Here's what i tried making:

```
<style id="1">
body {
background-color: pink;
}
</style>
```

```
<script>
var myVar = document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor = "brown";
</script>
```

The css is working, it is making the background pink, but the javascript isn't changing the css background color to brown.

Comment: That's not how it works. You would change the style on an element, or apply a new class to an element. You would not try and edit the stylesheet directly through script. `document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "brown"` or `document.querySelector("body").classList.add("brown")` (and then have a css style set for `.brown{ background-color:'brown'; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to set the background colour of the `<style>` tag. This is not how it works. Instead of setting the style of the `<style>` tag, you should set the style of the body itself. [This W3Schools Article](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp) gives an explanation if you need one.

```
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: pink;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body id="1">

    <script>
        document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor = "brown";
    </script>
</body>
```

It's also worth noting you don't need to assign the element to a variable unless you are going to use it later.

Comment: no need to assign an ID to the body. Simply use `querySelector('body')` or just `document.body`.

Comment: This is true, however in this case I felt that the OP would probably be more confused if we threw that in there, especially since the question can be applied more broadly to styling elements with JS.

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "brown";`, you can't put ids' or classes on non-elements. Try this;

```js
var myVar = document.body.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
```

```css
body {
background-color: pink;
}
```

This selects the body element, you could also put `id = "1"` on the body element.

Comment: Regarding id attributes on style tags... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797221/why-would-you-give-a-style-tag-an-id

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up the property over the selected element, in this case `myVar`

```
var myVar = document.getElementById("1");
myVar.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
```

Also tags should be in HTML, not in style:

```
<html>
<body  id="1">
ok
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant give the style Tag an ID. It is used to style the page inside the html file. And Body Tag is always unique. So you should not give that tag an ID. Just try to get the body tag in your javascript and change the background-color.

thx Kinglish for your information

Comment: You definitely can give style tags IDs, and there might be a few reasons you'd do it... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797221/why-would-you-give-a-style-tag-an-id

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'd change the body's background color with javascript.

```js
document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "brown";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try This :

```js
var myVar = document.getElementById("1").style.backgroundColor = "brown";
```

```css
 body {
          background-color: pink;
       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body id="1">
      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider adding explanations around your answers - the idea here is to educate and help people understand. Help them understand why their code isn't working

Comment: use  `id="1"` attribute in the body tag

Comment: That isn't an explanation. That is saying what you did, but not addressing why you did it.

Comment: you can't use the id attribute in the `<style>` tag

Comment: you can't use any attribute in <style> tag

Comment: I can't speak English but I am trying to understand ..

Comment: Actually you can put many different attributes in style tags - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style - you can use an ID attribute as well, if say, for some reason, you might want to remove that tag from the DOM.

Comment: no need to assign an ID to the body. Simply use `querySelector('body')` or just `document.body`.